# Object detecting without haarCascade.xml

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

**matchTemplate** works for only one object in the image, and object must have same size and rotation as template_image.
**haarTraining** takes long time for generating haarCascade.xml file. So Is there any other method of detecting objects, which has not any of these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has some very good samples for object detection (without haar cascades). You should have a look at [matcher_simple.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp) as a starting point. The next few to look at are [descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp) and [matching_to_many_images.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp). `matching_to_many_images.cpp` will probably be closest to what you are looking for as it breaks out the training and query phases for you, and allows for persistent storage of the training descriptors.

Also, have a look at the features2d [tutorials](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to detect objects, and there are many problems with each of them. It depends on the specific problem you are facing.

Haar object detection is a good one. The training phase is only needed once, then you can reuse the haarcascade.xml each time you run the program, and of course you can distribute it to others as well.

Other detectors include  HOG, LBP, SIFT. Note that all of them take some time for training.